# Intellij - Showing and property values and names

Tags: properties, ide, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ to edit a Spring Beans file, I am using a properties file to define some of the values of the beans.

In IntelliJ, when you open the bean file all of the properties are displaying their values (in grey).  When you edit this, it then displays the property name.

To get the value back, you have to close and then re-open the file

Is there another way to switch between the property name and value in an XML bean file other than closing and re-opening the file?

Answer (score 1):

IDEA is trying to be helpful here, showing you the actual values referred to by the property placeholders ("*${foo.bar}*").

You can see the raw placeholder expression by:

1. Double-clicking on the value
2. Putting the caret on the value, and pressing *Ctrl-Plus*